# Microsoft Graph API create folder with custom metadata column

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As part of creating a Team in Microsoft teams using the Graph API, I'm trying to create a folder in Microsoft Graph with a custom column - just a simple yes/no.

This is what I have so far:

```
            var newFolder = new DriveItem();
            newFolder.Name = folderName;
            newFolder.Folder = new Folder();

            newFolder.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            newFolder.AdditionalData.Add("@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename");

            var newSubFolder = _graphClient.Groups[team.RemoteId].Drive.Items[parentFolder.RemoteId].Children
                .Request().AddAsync(newFolder).Result;
```

However I need to add a custom column to this folder at creation time (or just after, if it needs to be in an update call). I was hoping I could do this easily through the Graph API but I can't seem to find any way to do this. Does anyone know how? (I have no idea how to access the underlying SharePoint API, by the way, so even if I knew how to do it with SharePoint that wouldn't help me much at the moment.)

Comment: Try the following steps:

(1) Create the folder:

POST /drives/{drive-id}/items/root/children

{
"name": "{test}",
"folder": { },
"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "fail"
}

(2) Get the created folder's item id and update the folder's content type, metadata::

PATCH /sites/{site-id}/lists/{library-name}/items/{item-id}
{
"contentType":
  {
    "id": "{content-type-id}"
  },
"fields":
  {
  "fieldname1": "{value}",
  "fieldname": "{value}"
  }
}

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Moving this to answer, so it can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps:

(1) Create the folder:

```
POST /drives/{drive-id}/items/root/children 
{ "name": "{test}", "folder": { }, "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "fail" }
```

(2) Get the created folder's item id and update the folder's content type, metadata:

```
PATCH /sites/{site-id}/lists/{library-name}/items/{item-id} { "contentType": { "id": "{content-type-id}" }, "fields": { "fieldname1": "{value}", "fieldname": "{value}" } }
```